# Unable to tab out of a text box in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have an aspx page that has a few text box fields and radio buttons that ultimately create a form for the customer to enter in data. The information is your typical stuff like zipcode, address, etc. When I on that page in IE and Chrome I can tab through all of the components on the page whether or not I add in any information in them (i.e. for the textboxes), but in Firefox it stops when I tab into the Zipcode textbox and only that one. There is some validation being checked on that textbox, but others as well which I can tab out of fine, and it only happens to be in Firefox. I would figured if this was something with the validation causing it to lock into that if I enter in valid data I still can't tab out of it.

I have tried setting the tab index to make sure that it goes in a particular order. To give you an idea of how it is laid out I have an asp:DropDownList then an asp:TextBox then another asp:DropDownList that populates once you tab out, or in this case, click out of the asp:TextBox. Do I need to set up an event handler to pick up the fact that I pressed tab to get out of that textbox? If so I'm not entirely sure how to do that, and it still wouldn't explain why it works in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Here is the mark up in question

```
<table class="table-forminput" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr class="table-forminputrow">
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="uxLabelEffectiveDate" runat="server" Text="Effective date:" ClientIDMode="Static" /><span class="requiredField">*</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxFieldEffectiveDate" runat="server" CssClass="inputselect"
                                ClientIDMode="Static" data-required="required" TabIndex="1">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>

                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="uxLabelPhoneNumber" runat="server" Text="Phone number:" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uxFieldPhoneNumber" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="phone" data-mask="999-999-9999" TabIndex="4" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="table-forminputrow">
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uxUpdatePanelZip" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxFieldZipCode" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="uxLabelZipCode" runat="server" Text="Zip code:" ClientIDMode="Static" /><span class="requiredField">*</span>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uxFieldZipCode" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext_short" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="uxFieldZipCode_TextChanged" data-required="required" MaxLength="5" TabIndex="1" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="uxLabelEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Email address:" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uxFieldEmail" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext_date" ClientIDMode="Static" TabIndex="5" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-forminputrow">
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="uxLabelCounty" runat="server" Text="County:" ClientIDMode="Static" /><span class="requiredField">*</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">

                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxFieldZipCode" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="uxFieldCounty" runat="server" CssClass="inputselect" ClientIDMode="Static" data-required="required" TabIndex="2">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="table-forminputrow">
                        <td class="text-middle text-right" id="uxTDChildOnlyLabel" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="uxLabelChildOnly" runat="server" Text="Child only coverage?" ClientIDMode="Static" /><span class="requiredField">*</span>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-middle text-left padding-bottom2" id="uxTDChildOnlyField" runat="server">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="uxFieldChildOnly" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="radioFlow" TabIndex="3">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Here is the validation for the zipcode specifically (it is in JavaScript)

```
       // validate zip code
    function validateZipCode() {
        var zipRegEx = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
        var zipCode = $('#uxFieldZipCode').val();
        if (zipCode != '' && !zipRegEx.test(zipCode)) {
            $('#uxFieldZipCode').addClass("ErrorBackground");
            addErrorMessage('<asp:literal ID="uxLiteralInvalidZipError" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Please enter a valid zip code." />');

        }

    }
```

Comment: It would help if you posted ASPX markup for the textbox in question as well as validation code for it.

Comment: Did you mean to set AutoPostback/OnTextChanged for the Zip field? That forces postback when control loses focus.

Comment: This isn't my code originally, but the way I understand it that is intentional as the county drop down list is populated based on the value entered into that zipcode field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with another dev we figured it out. Since we had the autopostback set when focus was lost we had to add the fact that a tab was pressed if it was pressed into the regular expression that was used for the validation.